# Nested Generic in Swift

Tags: swift, nested-generics

To put it simple, i have a generic class `Class1<X:Class2<Y>>`, and as far as i see Swift forces me to hardcode `Y` type in declaration of `Class1`, but i need `Y` to be variable as well as `X`.

**Long version**

I have a generic class  `DataSource<T:GenericItem>` class, which is than subclassed by non generic implementations (like `ItemsDataSource:DataSource<Item>`).

Now I want to create a some generic controller which can work with subclasses of my generic `DataSource`.

So I'm declaring controller like this `TableViewController<DS:GenericDataSource<GenericItem>>`, but in this case I'm not able to subclass it with `DataSource` parameter that is 
 a subclass of `GenericItem` as it's own parameter (i.e. i can not declare `SuperTableViewController<ItemsDataSource>`, because `ItemsDataSource` has `Item` generic parameter and not its parent `GenericItem`).

Any idea how can i create such generic controller?

Comment: If i understand your question, you must override the protocol also with an generic type.

Comment: Can you explain that little more? I do not have any protocols, just one generic class which i need to nest inside other generic?

Comment: I think the Problem is you say DS is generic but TableViewDataSource is hard typed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
class Class2<Y> { }

class Class1<X, Y where X: Class2<Y>> { }
```

Comment: Swift error: Superclass constraint 'GenericDataSource<T>' cannot depend on a type parameter